# What is the definition of `pattern` for git ls-remote?

Tags: git, git-ls-remote

What type of "pattern" does `git ls-remote` take?

[`man git-ls-remote`](https://manned.org/git-ls-remote.1) says:

> ```
>    <refs>...
>        When unspecified, all references, after filtering done with --heads
>        and --tags, are shown. When <refs>... are specified, only references
>        matching the given patterns are displayed.
> ```

It is a POSIX shell glob, regex, gitignore pattern, ...?

Comment: Reference patterns are always shell-style globs.

Comment: @torek Very helpful. You should post this as the answer. I found this helpful in testing those patterns too. http://www.globtester.com/

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, the documentation of `ls-remote` doesn't say much, but you can find this information in other pages. For example the documentation for [`git tag -l`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag#Documentation/git-tag.txt--l) says:

> The pattern is a shell wildcard (i.e., matched using fnmatch(3)).

As far as I can tell git only supports the [basic glob syntax](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html) but doesn't support "extended patterns" provided by the `FNM_EXTMATCH`.

I think the filtering is actually implemented by [`wildmatch()`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/wildmatch.c), so the behavior may differ from the standard `fnmatch`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that Git 2.40 (Q1 2023) does slightly update the definition of a pattern for `git ls-remote`.

See [commit d9ec3b0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d9ec3b0dc0fe51b4e56df5a809d3a1f8d83b89eb), [commit baebde7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/baebde7d19a9281242f4542267b70e2565f63886) (10 Feb 2023) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6aac634](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6aac634f818a35414c7541d86039e29aa0aa7562), 22 Feb 2023)</sup>

> ### [`doc/ls-remote`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d9ec3b0dc0fe51b4e56df5a809d3a1f8d83b89eb): clarify pattern format
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> We document that you can specify "refs" to `ls-remote`, but we don't explain any further than that they are "matched" as patterns.
> Since this can be interpreted in a lot of ways, **let's clarify that they are tail-matched globs**.
>
> Likewise, let's use the word "patterns" to refer to them consistently, rather than "refs" (both here and in the quick "`-h`" help), and mention more explicitly that only one pattern needs to be matched (though there is also an example already that shows this in action).

`git ls-remote` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d9ec3b0dc0fe51b4e56df5a809d3a1f8d83b89eb/Documentation/git-ls-remote.txt#L14):

> `[--symref] [<repository> [<patterns>...]]`

`git ls-remote` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d9ec3b0dc0fe51b4e56df5a809d3a1f8d83b89eb/Documentation/git-ls-remote.txt#L90-L97):

> ### `<patterns>...`:
>
> When unspecified, all references, after filtering done
> with `--heads` and `--tags`, are shown.
>
> When `<patterns>...` are
> specified, only references matching one or more of the given
> patterns are displayed.
> Each pattern is interpreted as a **[glob](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-glob)** which is matched against
> the "tail" of a ref, starting either from the start of the ref
> (so a full name like `refs/heads/foo` matches) or from a slash
> separator (so `bar` matches `refs/heads/bar` but not
> `refs/heads/foobar`).